# How to filter from airflow variables in python

Tags: python, airflow

I have some variables in Airflow and I'm trying to call this variables in python list, but I am not able to do that. If I use the values, its works, but I have big list, so I need to use airflow variables

This code works good

```
filtered_data = [x for x in data if x['id_job'] in [14,67]]
```

But,I am trying this one and not work

```
id_job=get_vars['id_job']

filtered_data = [x for x in data if x['id_job'] = Variable.get('id_job')]
```

I have created this variables 'id_job' in Airflow variables with respective values.
When I print id_job from get_vars I can see the list of my values, but not working when I call inside the list.
Does someone knows how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call the `Variable.get`, you are making a request to the backend database. It is a good practice to save the variables as a JSON, so that you call once the entire JSON file and after that, you do whatever you want with all the variables, saving the database a lot of stress.

For that, you should have a file like the following (called, for instance, variables_json.json):

```
{
    "variables_secret": {
        "job_id_61": "61",
        "s3_airflow": "airflow"
    }
}
```

Then, importing it for Airflow 1.10 versions is:

```
airflow variables -i variables_secret.json
```

or if Airflow > 2.0:

```
airflow variables import variables_secret.json
```

Afterwards, the python code is:

```
variables = Variable.get('variables_secret', deserialize_json=True)
```

Finally, you would have access to all of your variables like:

```
variables['id_job_61']
```

And with the dict you can do whatever check you need

Comment: I had already tried it

My old code:
`code`get_vars = Variable.get('my_variables', default_var='', deserialize_json=True)

filtered_data = [x for x in data if x['id_job'] = get_vars['id_job']]`code`

When I do this I receive Broken DAG: invalid syntax(line 2)

Answer (score 0):

I had already tried it.
My old code:

```
get_vars = Variable.get('my_variables', default_var='', deserialize_json=True) 
filtered_data = [x for x in data if x['id_job'] = get_vars['id_job']]
```

When I do this I receive Broken DAG: invalid syntax(line 2).
I think the reason is because it's on a list, but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

For equality expressions in Python you need double equal signs; a single equal sign is an assignment operator.  Try this for line 2:

```py
filtered_data = [x for x in data if x['id_job'] == get_vars['id_job']]
```